# GDAL: reading rasters from a private google cloud bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gdal

I want to read raster datasets from a private google cloud storage bucket through the `gs://` URIs using `GDAL`. According to the [VSI documentation](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsigs-google-cloud-storage-files) one way of authenticating is `GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.

I have these credentials for a service account that has access to the target bucket, but when setting them as environment variables I get a `403` response.

Further more, trying to access a public dataset like

```sh
gdalinfo /vsigs/gcp-public-data-sentinel-2/tiles/32/V/LQ/S2B_MSIL1C_20181108T111249_N0207_R137_T32VLQ_20181108T113514.SAFE/MTD_MSIL1C.xml
```

also returns a `403` error with the credentials set up like this.

When going though the motion with `gsutil config -a` I'm required to specify the `project-id`, which I don't have for these credentials.

I've tried using different credentials where I know the `project-id` and everything seems to suddenly work.

The only relevant discussions I've found ([[1]](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1718), [[2]](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2227)) don't mention anything about the `project-id`.

So, my questions are

- using a credential setup like this, is specifying the corresponding `project-id` a mandatory requirement?
- is there a way to set these credentials in `env` and not in `.boto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a mix-up with the credentials. Without (valid) credentials, reading public datasets is also not possible.

One way of authenticating is using a valid `GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` + `GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` combination for a service account with sufficient permissions.

These can be set as environment variables or stored in the `.boto` file.

If stored in the `.boto` file, this can be done manually

```yaml
[Credentials]
gs_access_key_id=<YOURKEY>
gs_secret_access_key=<YOURSECRET>
```

or by running `gsutil config -a` ich which case you will be asked for a `project-id`. But at least for this purpose, it doesn't seem to make a difference if this id is correct as long as one inputs a something.